# java MediaPlayer doesn't release resource

Tags: java, swing, media-player, jmf

I use javax.media.Player to player video in java Swing and it works just right. But when I need to delete a video just played, it prompts that the video is occupied by some program, surely the MediaPlayer. Anybody can teach me how to release resource at the end video playing?

code as follows:

```
public class VideoPlayerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    private Player mediaPlayer;
    private Component video = null;
    private Component controls = null;

    /**
     * Creates new form VideoPlayerPanel
     */
    public VideoPlayerPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public void play(URL url) {
        if (video != null) {
            remove(video);
        }
        if (controls != null) {
            remove(controls);
        }
        try {
            mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
            video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
            controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
            this.add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            validate();
            revalidate();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VideoPlayerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VideoPlayerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VideoPlayerPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

   ......               
}`
```

Comment: Not unless you show some code

Comment: hello @fge, codes added.

Comment: I'd imagine that unless you close or deal lactate the player, it's not likely to release the resource, as its unlikely that the player will want to keep it in memory

Comment: The problem is that the video control panel will disappear with the video panel if I close the MediaPlayer, but I want to play the video again by clicking the 'play' button. @MadProgrammer

Comment: This is why the file is not been closed and therefore is locked

Comment: Isn't there any way that I can close the file with the control panel still there? @MadProgrammer

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  I think it's the players way of preventing possible errors